# Do Flash Locale Shared Objects behave like cookies?

Tags: flash, actionscript, local-storage, local-shared-object

Cookies are sent to the server per each request making them a slow choice for data storage. However, what's the case with Flash's LSOs? Are they only script accessible and not sent to the server?

If it matters, I'm looking for a way to store data on the client using Flash and performance does matter here (as well as the size limits). I know that the default size limit is 100 kB for LSOs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actualy you can write the data to disk whenever you want by using flush(minDiskSpace:int = 0)
where you can specify the size that it will require.

If you want those data stored on an FMS just use getRemote() instead of getLocale();

Comment: Financial Management Service? Could you elaborate a bit more or show me a link to some docs?

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mind with size limit, then I would use the flash's way. Also, users usually cleans their cookies more often than flash shared objects (that's what I guess)